# Bound on the trace of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, traces

Suppose $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and we can bound its trace as $l \le tr(A) \le L$. I am wondering if it is possible to find the upper and lower bounds on the trace of $A^{-1}$ based on $tr(A)$ and its bound? What inequalities hold and under what conditions?

**Edit:** I should add that there is a lower bound for eigenvalues of the matrix $A$, i.e., $\lambda_i(A)\ge \lambda_0$.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to find a lower bound but not an upper bound. Just use the fact that the trace is the sum of eigenvalues, and that the inverse matrix has inverse eigenvalues.

Comment: What if we know that there is a lower bound on eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

Diagonalizing the positive semi-definite matrix $A$ (say $n\times n$) and assuming $0<l<L<\infty$, we reduce the problem to the following:

> What are the best upper and lower bounds on $\sum_1^n \frac1{t_j}$ over all positive $t_j$'s such that $l\le\sum_1^n t_j\le L$?$

If $n\ge2$, we can take $t_1=(L+l)/2$ and $t_2,\dots,t_n$ close to $0$. So, we see that there is no finite upper bound on $\sum_1^n \frac1{t_j}$.

On the other hand, we have the inequalities
$$\sum_1^n \frac1{t_j}\ge n^2\Big/\sum_1^n t_j\ge\frac{n^2}L, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and the lower bound $\frac{n^2}L$ on $\sum_1^n \frac1{t_j}$ is exact, as it is attained when $t_j=L/n$ for all $j$; the first inequality in \eqref{1} follows immediately from (say) the [HM-GM-AM-QM inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think this answer does not assume any lower bound on the eigenvalues of $A$. I am wondering if lower bound on eigenvalues has any impact?

Comment: Any lower bound on the eigenvalues $t_j$ of $A$ must be $\le L/n$ for $tr(A)$ to be $\le L$. So, the values $t_j=L/n$ for all $j$ will be allowed, and these values provide for the exact lower bound $n^2/L$, given in the answer. So, the answer to your comment is: No, of course not -- any admissible lower bound on the eigenvalues will not have any impact.

Comment: @Amin : Do you have a further response to my answer and comment?

Comment: Based on the search, I found that $tr(A^{-1})tr(A)\le n^2 \kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the condition number of matrix $A$. In the following post, I defined matrix $V$ and I wanna find an upper bound on trace of inverse of $A$ that depends on $t$. My guess is that this upper bound is a decreasing function of $t$ (I guess that $t$ should appear in the denominator, not in the nominator). I should mention that vectors $\mathbf{x}_s$ are not chosen by adversaries. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626468/bound-on-the-condition-number-of-a-psd-matrix?rq=1

Comment: I generate samples and this behavior is observed

Comment: @Amin : Please finalize the current question (fully answered) before asking new ones.